# jquery to get the height of withing the table cell

Tags: jquery

When i try to get the height of an div class="txtTruncate02" in jquery each function it return the same value for all row, even the content is more in second row!!!

any idea to get the height of the div on each cell ?

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="txtTruncate02">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Site Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Site Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor  </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>12 Jun 2014</div>
                            <div>12:35:23</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a>Robyn McCormick</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>Build</td>
                        <td class="lastCell">
                            <div class="switchContainerFalse switchContainer"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="txtTruncate02">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site AmetLorem Ipsum Dolor Site Amet.&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>12 Jun 2014</div>
                            <div>12:35:23</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a>Robyn McCormick</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>Peer Review</td>
                        <td class="lastCell">
                            <div class="switchContainerFalse switchContainer"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Could you please put the jquery code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve it with `.css("height")` you're going to get the same values. Use:

```
var heights = [];
$(".txtTruncate02").each(function () {
    heights.push($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: I am trying the jquery height method only, still i getting same height value for all the cell...  $("#smscNotesTable tbody tr").each(function(){
  //$(".txtTruncate02").addClass("txtTruncate02Collapse");
  alert($(".txtTruncate02").height());
 });

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollHeight` for getting content height

```
$('.txtTruncate02').each(function(){
  console.log(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55CV4/)**

Comment: $('.txtTruncate02').each(function(){
 alert(this.scrollHeight);
 }); This is also return the same value for all the cell :(

Answer (score 0):

`.each` method used to traverse selected dom element

```
 $(".txtTruncate02").each(function(){
   alert($(this).height());
});
```

OR

```
$("table tr").each(function(){ alert($(this).height()); })
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eZjXc/3/)

Comment: Thanks for you help, instead write each fns on .txtTruncate02, i have written on the table....

Comment: i think u need this type of $("table tr").each(function(){
   alert($(this).height());
});